# Problem using LIMIT in a MySQL subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, limit

I have a SQL query as follows

> SELECT * FROM `epf_application` WHERE
>   `application_id` IN
>   (SELECT
>   `application_id` FROM
>   `epf_application_device_type` WHERE
>   device_type_id IN
>   (SELECT
>   `device_type_id` FROM
>   `epf_device_type` WHERE
>   `name`="someDevice") LIMIT 30) LIMIT
>   30

When I run it in phpMyAdmin, I get the following error

> 1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME
>   subquery'

From the error, I am guessing that there is a problem with placing `LIMIT` in a subquery. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: As the error says, that feature apparently isn't yet supported. You may need to get your hands dirty and use a temporary table or something.

Comment: Nested SQL queries are also bad on performance. FYI

Comment: @FinalForm: Indeed, I think David needs to learn a bit about `JOINS`.

Comment: @josh.trow Thanks for the tip. I'll learn `JOINS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 ea.* 
FROM 
 epf_application ea JOIN epf_application_device ead 
  ON ead.application_id = ea.application_id 
 JOIN epf_device_type edt 
  ON edt.device_type_id = ead.device_type_id 
WHERE 
 edt.name = 'someDevice' 
LIMIT 30
```